I went to my second job
I have been wondering if in certain contexts it is possible to say that we "go to the job". Normally "job" is reserved for meanings closer to "position" and "post" whereas the noun "work" is used to indicate the process of earning money or a place to do so. An example could be simple "I go to work".
Nevertheless, let's imagine that one has two jobs and needs to commute between them. Would such a person say that after finishing his first job he went to his second job? Is it natural or a native speaker would rather use a different combination of words to express such a meaning?
I am curious to learn about your perspective on the subject.

"I went to my second job" is fine (Google my second job), "go to the job" is probably not (as you say, "I go to work" is much better). This feels like an English Language Learners question though.

'I go to work' means something different from 'I'm going to work in ten minutes': it means 'I regularly attend a workplace to do a paid job.'  'After finishing his first job he went to his second job' could be one-off or habitual, but doesn't carry the sense of 'he goes to work' = 'he works'.

A mobile fitter might go to one job and then to the next job. If you have two jobs – employments – you might go from your day job to your night job.

It would be perfectly reasonable and common to say he went to his second job (or third job, etc.). If there were only two, you might say his other job. If one job was during the day and the other at night, you could say he went to his day job or his night job.
